# Hangman in stateless JavaScript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, hangman

I just want some feedback to improve readability and structure for this implementation of Hangman. The goal was to write it in a purely functional way. However, coming from an imperative background, I found it difficult to organize functional code.

```js
function Hangman(word, revealed = word.replace(/\w/g, '_'), errors = 0) {
  const hasLost = errors > 5;
  const hasWon = !hasLost && word === revealed;

  const tryGuess = (letter, character, guess) =>
    new RegExp(letter, "i").test(character) ? character : '_';

  const revealCharacter = (letter, character, guess) => /_/.test(guess) ? 
    tryGuess(letter, character, guess) : guess;

  const revealLetters = (letter, [head, ...rest], [guess, ...guessed]) => {
    const character = / /.test(head) ? ' ' : revealCharacter(letter, head, guess);
    return rest.length ?
      character + revealLetters(letter, rest, guessed) : character;
  }

  const getErrorCount = (guess, word, count) =>
    new RegExp(guess, "i").test(word) ? count : count + 1;

  const getResult = () => hasLost ? 'You lose' : 'You win';

  if (!hasWon && !hasLost) {
    this.guess = letter => new Hangman(word,
      revealLetters(letter, word, revealed),
      getErrorCount(letter, word, errors));
    console.log(revealed, errors);
  } else {
    console.log(getResult());
  }
}

const game = new Hangman('Agile Development');
game.guess('e').guess('a').guess('t').guess('z');
```

**UPDATE**: Below is the revised edition of the code with the advised changes. The code base looks much cleaner and I decided to try to stick to only using primitives and functions. Having each function accomplish a single task increased the code size, but definitely improved the readability and maintainability of the code.

```js
function Hangman(text, revealed = null, errors = 0) {
  { // constructor
    if (revealed === null) {
      return Hangman(text, revealMatch(/\s/g, text), 0);
    }

    if (isDone()) {
      console.info(getGameStatus());
    } else {
     console.info(arguments);
      return makeGuess;
    }
  }
  
  function createMatchedCharacterList(matcher) {
    return (revealed, actual, index) => {
      if (matcher.test(actual)) {
        revealed[index] = actual;
      }
      return revealed;
    }
  }
  
  function revealMatch(matcher, text) {
    return text.split('').reduce(createMatchedCharacterList(matcher), [])
  }
  
  function revealCharacter(guess) {
    return Object.assign([], revealed, revealMatch(new RegExp(guess, 'i'), text));
  }
  
  function makeGuess(guess) {
    return (hasCharacter(guess) && !hasGuessed(guess)) ?
      Hangman(text, revealCharacter(guess), errors) : 
      Hangman(text, revealed, errors + 1);
  }
  
  function hasCharacter(character) {
    return text.search(character) > -1;
  }
  
  function hasGuessed(guess) {
    return revealed.join('').search(guess) > -1;
  }
  
  function hasLost() {
    return errors > 5;
  }
  
  function hasWon() {
    return text === revealed.join('');
  }
  
  function isDone() {
    return hasLost() || hasWon();
  }
  
  function getGameStatus() {
    return isDone() ? hasLost() ? 'You lose' : 'You win' : 'Incomplete';
  }
}

console.log(Hangman('eatz')('e')('a')('t')('z'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a great question,

- `hasLost` and `hasWon` should be functions
- You should write functions with the keyword `function`, otherwise you get a mess of anonymous functions in stack-traces. The fat arrow syntax was only meant for inline functions.
- `head` is not a great variable name, I don't know what it is supposed to be from the name
- On the whole, the challenge in pure fp is to never assign, which you do a few times, read this for good measure: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33114654/7602
- I am not sure I like that the `guess` function creates a new `Hangman` object every single time, there has to be a cleaner approach.

I found an interesting guide: https://drboolean.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/ which states that `this` should be avoided.. Meanwhile, this is my `this` littered approach. It follows all my recommendations, and shows where I feel fat arrows have a place. I will try to rewrite again once I finish the guide ;)

```
function Hangman(word, copy, mistakes){

  //Initialize again, no assignments here ;)
  if(!copy){
    return Hangman(word, '_'.repeat(word.length), 0 );
  }

  //Non Exposed functions requiring context
  const won = (() => {
    return function won(){
      return word == copy;                             
    };                          
  })();

  const lost = (() => {
    return function lost(){
      return mistakes > 5;
    }
  })();

  const updateMistakes = (() => {
    return function updateMistakes(oldCopy , newCopy){
      return mistakes += oldCopy == newCopy ? 1 : 0;
    }
  })();

  const applyGuess = (() => {
    return function applyGuess(letter){
      return copy  = word.split('').map( (c,i) => letter == c ?  c : copy[i] ).join('');
    }
  })();

  //Exposed Functions
  function guess(){
    return function guess(letter){ 
      if(!done()){
        updateMistakes( copy , applyGuess(letter) );      
      }
      this.display();
      return this;
    };
  }

  function display(){
    return function display(){
      console.log( won()? 'You won' : lost() ? 'You lost' : copy + ' ' + mistakes );
    };
  }

  //Return object
  return {
    guess : guess(),
    display: display(),    
  }

  //Pure function?
  function done(){
    return won() || lost();
  }  

}

const game = Hangman('Agile Development');
game.guess('e').guess('a').guess('t').guess('z');
```

Okay, 2nd version with far less `this`, many more clean functions:

```
function Hangman(word, copy, mistakes){

  //Initialize again, no assignments here ;)
  if(!copy){
    return Hangman(word, '_'.repeat(word.length), 0 );
  }

  //Exposed Functions
  function guess(){
    return function guess(letter){ 
      if( !done( won(word,copy), lost(mistakes) ) ){
        //An assignment, it was unavoidable I think
        mistakes = updateMistakes( mistakes, copy , copy = applyGuess(word,copy,letter) );      
      }
      display(word, copy, mistakes, letter );
      return this;
    };
  }

  //Return object, kind pointless now that there is only 1 function :/
  return {
    guess : guess()
  }

  //Not entirely pure function, not cacheable
  function display(word, copy, mistakes, letter){
    console.log( won(word,copy) ? 'You won' :
                 lost(mistakes) ? 'You lost' :
                 copy + ' ' + mistakes + ' You tried (' + letter + ')' );
  }

  //Pure functions!!
  function applyGuess(word, copy, letter){
    return word.split('').map( (c,i) => letter == c ?  c : copy[i] ).join('');
  }

  function updateMistakes(mistakes, oldCopy , newCopy){
    return mistakes + (oldCopy == newCopy ? 1 : 0 );
  }

  function done(won, lost){
    return won || lost;
  }

  function won(word, copy){
    return word == copy;                             
  }   

  function lost(mistakes){
      return mistakes > 5;
  }

}

const game = Hangman('Agile Development');
game.guess('e').guess('a').guess('t').guess('z');
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and analysis. Without the `this`, it's great that the game now can be instantiated without being `new`ed. Why are methods like `lost` in self-executing function calls? Is this a stylistic thing or a JavaScript thing?

Comment: That's to create the closure,  though I am sure this can be done better.

Comment: I just tested creating a function called `won` inside Hangman instead of assigning it to a `const` and the closure still works fine. So just using plain functions might be cleaner.